# Flutter - How to manage the position and scale of SVG Paths that must maintain the relationship with images

Tags: flutter, dart, svg, flutter-layout, flutter-web

**Hi everyone, first of all I want to thank you even just for being interested in my problem.**
So, I state that it is the first time that I use StackOverflow to solve a problem but after hours of trying and researching I have unfortunately not been able to conclude anything good.

*What I am trying to create in Flutter is a website that has the following function: when you click on one of the people in the photo its outline must light up and the state of the text widget on the left side change accordingly.*

To be able to achieve this goal, I inserted the image (3640x5050) as a background image of a Container positioned on the left side of the screen with the BoxFit.cover property in order to adapt it to the screen measurements, always keeping the subjects in view.

Then I used Figma to create the vector paths of each of the subjects and with the help of the path_drawing package I implemented them; here perhaps a first problem arises, since the paths refer to the enormous dimensions of the original photo, I had to resize them at least in height so that they wouldn't be cut (the dimensions of a 'mask' have therefore become approximately 271x969, where 969 is the maximum height visible from the browser on a computer with 1920x1080 as resolution).

Finally in Photoshop I created the bright outline of each subject with a transparent background, and, after exporting them in .png, I made sure that when you click on a character, the trasparent image (containing only its outline) of the same size (3640x5050) and with the same widget properties is placed above the background image.

Using this method I was able to obtain the desired result on my computer, however the problem arises when the size of the screen or window varies: while the background image and those containing the glowing outlines adapt and change size while remaining consistent with each other, the svg paths (positioned with an offset and adapted with a Transform.scale) obviously, as I have implemented them, do not adapt to the changes of the image they should refer to, making my efforts in vain.

I tried to think of a solution on my own but perhaps due to my incompetence or ineptitude I have not yet been able to find a solution, after all I admit that I am not yet a great connoisseur of Flutter, I am still learning. Therefore, I am truly grateful to all of you who are ready to grant me their help or some of their knowledge and experience.
I rely on you.

I attach my code and some photos to make the explanation clearer.

**Thanks everyone in advance.**

The class of the page:

```
    // ignore: file_names
import 'package:asdwebsite/widgets/ProjectRelated/Web/MenuFloatingButton.dart';
import 'package:asdwebsite/widgets/ProjectRelated/Web/WebsiteDrawer.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_drawing/path_drawing.dart';

class HistoryPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HistoryPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HistoryPageState createState() => _HistoryPageState();
}

class _HistoryPageState extends State<HistoryPage> {
  final double dim = 1;
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey();
  final GlobalKey<MenuFloatingButtonState> _MenuFloatingButtonKey = GlobalKey();

  final double _diff = 200;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  String selected = "";

  String title = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    if (selected == "") {
      title = "";
    } else if (selected == "p1") {
      title = "PERSON 1";
    } else if (selected == "p2") {
      title = "PERSON 2";
    }

    return Scaffold(
      endDrawerEnableOpenDragGesture: false,
      drawerEdgeDragWidth: 0.0,
      body: Scaffold(
        endDrawerEnableOpenDragGesture: true,
        //drawerEdgeDragWidth: 0.0,
        onEndDrawerChanged: (isOpened) {
          _MenuFloatingButtonKey.currentState?.externalChange(isOpened);
        },
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        body: backgroundImage(height, width),

        endDrawer: const WebsiteDrawer(),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: MenuFloatingButton(
        key: _MenuFloatingButtonKey,
        open: (() => {_scaffoldKey.currentState?.openEndDrawer()}),
        close: (() => {_scaffoldKey.currentState?.closeEndDrawer()}),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endTop,
    );
  }

  Widget backgroundImage(double height, double width) {
    final double resizedWidth = width * 1 / 2 + _diff + 40;
    return Container(
      color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Stack(
            children: [
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                child: Container(
                  width: resizedWidth,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                          image: const AssetImage(
                              'images/Background-Image.jpg'),
                          alignment:
                              Alignment.center.add(const Alignment(-0.1, 0.12)),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                ),
              ),
              Opacity(
                opacity: selected == "p1" ? 1 : 0,
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  child: Container(
                    width: resizedWidth,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                            image: AssetImage('images/$selected-glow.png'),
                            alignment: Alignment.center
                                .add(const Alignment(-0.1, 0.12)),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Opacity(
                opacity: selected == "p2" ? 1 : 0,
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  child: Container(
                    width: resizedWidth,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                            image: AssetImage('images/$selected-glow.png'),
                            alignment: Alignment.center
                                .add(const Alignment(-0.1, 0.12)),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                child: Transform.scale(
                  scale: 0.8,
                  child: _getClippedImage(
                    clipper: _Clipper(
                      svgPath: p1Path,
                      offset: Offset(_diff, 12),
                    ),
                    onClick: () {
                      setState(() {
                        if (selected == "") {
                          selected = "p1";
                        } else {
                          selected = "";
                        }
                      });
                    },
                    image: 'images/transp.png',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                child: Transform.scale(
                  scale: 1.30,
                  child: _getClippedImage(
                    clipper: _Clipper(
                      svgPath: p2Path,
                      offset: const Offset(90, 30),
                    ),
                    onClick: () {
                      setState(() {
                        if (selected == "") {
                          selected = "p2";
                        } else {
                          selected = "";
                        }
                      });
                    },
                    image: 'images/transp.png',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Container(
              height: height,
              width: (width * 1 / 2) - (_diff / 4),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topRight: Radius.circular(_diff),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(_diff),
                  )),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(100.0),
                child: Text(
                  "$title",
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelMedium,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget _getClippedImage({
  required _Clipper clipper,
  required String image,
  required void Function() onClick,
}) {
  return ClipPath(
    clipper: clipper,
    child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: onClick,
        child: Image.asset(
          image,
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        )),
  );
}

class _Clipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  _Clipper(
      {required this.svgPath,
      this.additionalSvgPath = "",
      this.offset = Offset.zero});

  String additionalSvgPath;
  String svgPath;
  Offset offset;


  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = parseSvgPathData(svgPath);
    /*if (additionalSvgPath != "") {
      Path path2 = parseSvgPathData(additionalSvgPath);
      path.addPath(path2, Offset.zero);
    }*/

    return path.shift(offset);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}

const String p1Path =
    "m10.278 170.408 4.728 15.211c.754 3.631 2.261 10.977 2.261 11.305 0 .329.822 3.837 1.233 5.55l2.877 2.261 3.906-.822 2.055-2.672 2.466-3.084 2.672.617-.412 4.111-2.261 8.428c-.891 1.507-2.713 4.563-2.877 4.728-.164.164-2.261 1.85-3.289 2.672l2.261 3.7c1.027 7.674 3.084 23.145 3.084 23.639v6.167l1.029 6.783 5.55 21.584 4.934 16.856 5.344 16.033 2.055 11.717v17.678c.412 2.535 1.233 7.647 1.233 7.811 0 .164.547 4.728.822 6.988l2.466 11.511-3.289 21.994 4.522 1.85c.891 1.233 2.672 3.865 2.672 4.522 0 .822-.205 2.877-.412 3.289-.164.329.48 3.974.822 5.756l.617 9.661v8.222c0 .164 1.096 6.783 1.645 10.072.617 4.041 1.891 12.457 2.055 13.772.164 1.316 1.165 8.086 1.645 11.305l1.439 11.511 1.233 9.456 1.027 13.979 2.466 2.055-.412 3.495 1.439 1.85c.275.893.822 2.754.822 3.084 0 .329-.959 1.78-1.439 2.466-.275 2.536-.822 7.77-.822 8.428 0 .822 1.233 1.85 1.439 2.055.164.164.617 2.397.822 3.495l-2.261 1.645 1.233 23.434c-.412.275-1.316.863-1.645 1.027-.412.205-2.877.412-3.7.617s-3.084 1.439-3.495 1.645c-.329.164-1.782 1.574-2.466 2.261-.343 1.027-1.068 3.125-1.233 3.289-.164.164-1.85 1.715-2.672 2.466-.205.958-.617 2.918-.617 3.084 0 .205.617 4.111.617 4.522 0 .329.822 3.565 1.233 5.139.547 1.574 1.48 5.057.822 6.373-.822 1.645-2.261 1.233-3.084 1.439s-5.344.412-6.167.412h-8.425l-.617 1.85c.412 1.645 1.275 5.057 1.439 5.55.164.494.48 4.728.617 6.783.617.341 1.891.904 2.055.412.205-.617 9.867 0 10.072 0 .164 0 4.454 2.603 6.578 3.906l4.111 6.373 1.233 8.428-1.645 11.1 1.645 3.289 4.317 1.027v13.567h-8.219v2.261l2.261 2.877 9.867 3.289-1.645 4.522 1.645 7.606 2.055 1.85 4.934 8.838 3.495 15.006v12.334c-.754 1.645-2.508 5.016-3.495 5.344-1.233.412-3.906 2.261-4.934 2.877-.822.494-2.809 4.863-3.7 6.988l-3.289 7.811-6.167 10.072-4.111 5.344-8.838 3.906-8.633 2.877-7.195 2.055h-5.756l-2.466-2.055H12.744c1.096 9.937 2.961 29.806 1.645 29.806s-.547 2.603 0 3.906l-1.645 10.689-4.317 15.417-1.645 16.856-6.371 6.784 8.018 54.884 2.877 21.378 2.672 1.645h6.578c1.439 2.191 4.44 6.702 4.934 7.195.494.494 1.165 8.292 1.439 12.128.137 6.442.576 19.528 1.233 20.35.822 1.027 3.906 11.717 6.373 16.239 1.973 3.618 5.481 5.62 6.988 6.167l2.466-3.7c2.397-.958 7.195-3.084 7.195-3.906s-2.466-3.77-3.7-5.139l-3.495-6.167 7.195-4.522c-1.096-2.877-3.043-9.004-2.055-10.483 1.233-1.85 0-14.389 0-16.033 0-1.316 1.37-8.633 2.055-12.128v-15.211l5.344-12.744 4.728-1.645 4.728-6.988-1.439-10.072-4.728-5.139 4.728-36.589c.617-2.125 1.973-6.537 2.466-7.195.494-.658 2.809-3.153 3.906-4.317-.547-1.986-1.686-6.455-1.85-8.428-.164-1.973 1.165-2.191 1.85-2.055.547-1.027 1.809-3.495 2.466-5.139.822-2.055 4.728-6.578 4.728-8.018s2.055-4.934 2.672-6.988c.494-1.645-1.575-1.369-2.672-1.027v-6.578l6.988-9.456 5.756-11.717 6.373-11.305 7.811-12.128 12.95-10.483 10.689-10.278c3.426-2.055 10.442-6.373 11.1-7.195.658-.822 10.415-3.358 15.211-4.522l15.623-6.167 16.651-4.934 10.072-1.85 1.027-7.4-4.934-9.045-3.289-10.483-2.877-7.811v-9.661l-4.317-13.567v-38.435l6.167-20.555 7.606-23.023 3.289-11.305 8.222-14.183 12.128-12.334 4.93-3.293c1.85-1.508 5.715-4.852 6.373-6.167s4.659-.547 6.578 0h6.784l7.811-2.672 8.018-2.055 11.922 2.055h20.761l11.305 2.672-1.645-4.728-5.961-9.867-3.7-6.373-3.906-8.633 2.261-10.483 4.111-12.334v-9.456l-2.466-4.317-20.762-25.694v-5.55l-1.439-14.801-1.027-1.027-5.548-13.772 2.055-24.256-2.055-3.495-8.633-10.483 2.672-10.278-1.645-19.733c-1.233-10.483-3.74-31.614-3.906-32.272-.164-.658-1.165-6.988-1.645-10.072v-7.195l-1.645-2.261-26.106-21.378-51.39-6.578-7.606-2.672 4.728-4.934c2.466-2.604 7.647-8.018 8.633-8.838 1.233-1.027 3.084-8.633 3.084-10.072s0-3.495 1.645-4.317 4.934-2.055 4.934-2.672c0-.494 3.152-2.125 4.728-2.877l-2.261-3.289 8.428-6.373v-7.195l-6.167-10.483-4.728-15.623-3.495-14.594c-.685-3.289-2.261-10.278-3.084-11.922s-3.22-8.496-4.317-11.717v-8.838l-4.934-25.078c-.959-4.042-3.125-12.622-4.111-14.594-1.233-2.466-4.317-9.25-5.344-9.25-.822 0-3.084-5.756-4.111-8.633v-7.402l-5.344-3.084-8.84-4.317-11.922-5.139-10.483-5.55c-2.946-1.439-9.25-4.481-10.894-5.139-1.641-.66-10.274-.96-14.385-1.03-8.358 1.575-25.53 5.016-27.339 6.167-2.262 1.439-12.745 6.783-13.772 7.606-.822.658-8.428 7.263-12.128 10.483L32.889 40.495l-5.55 12.744 1.85 9.867-1.85 10.483-2.055 5.756-6.167 5.344-2.877 8.838-2.261 14.185 1.027 12.128 1.233 5.55 5.961 3.084v9.66l3.084 3.906c.137 3.7.329 11.305 0 12.128s-4.248 5.961-6.167 8.428l-8.838 7.811ZM387.476 609.89c-8.222-6.713-24.79-20.309-25.284-20.967h-1.645c-.617.275-1.85.863-1.85 1.027v3.289c0 .494 1.233 2.125 1.85 2.877.205.958.617 3.125.617 4.111 0 .986 1.096.958 1.645.822.343 1.233 1.109 3.781 1.439 4.111.329.329 1.782 1.233 2.466 1.645l3.084 2.055 1.233 5.756-2.672 1.233.617 1.645c-.412.412-1.439 1.316-2.261 1.645-1.027.412-2.466 2.877-2.466 3.289 0 .329 1.096 1.92 1.645 2.672l-1.645.822-1.439-.412v4.522c0 .822-1.439 1.439-1.645 2.055-.164.494-1.027 2.948-1.439 4.111-.617 1.164-1.85 3.618-1.85 4.111 0 .494-.822 1.164-1.233 1.439.343 1.439 1.068 4.522 1.233 5.344.164.822 3.357 2.397 4.934 3.084l3.084.822 4.728 2.466 11.1-6.373 48.306 40.7 30.012 30.012 11.305-10.895-3.906-3.7.617-2.261-1.233-2.672-1.233-4.317 12.95-12.744c1.508.205 4.728.658 5.55.822.822.164 1.439-2.536 1.645-3.906l-.412-3.906-7.4-6.783-9.045.822-24.666 18.09-51.594-46.045 6.988-5.961 19.322 15.828 1.027 2.877 2.877 1.85 2.877-1.439v-3.289l-1.439-2.261-3.289-.822-21.378-19.733c.275-2.191.658-6.702 0-7.195-.822-.617-5.139-3.495-6.167-4.317s0-2.261 0-2.877-1.439-3.084-2.261-3.084h-3.7Z";

const String p2Path =
    "m80.052 124.201 2.157 16.366L93.754 170l-6.978 11.037 6.978 11.798-2.791 15.731-5.582-12.687-6.724-1.396-5.709 7.358H62.545L48.209 136l6.724-5.582-1.396-13.448-3.933-6.851-5.328 2.284-3.679-2.284-12.94-51.127L14.209.254.381 4.694l11.545 54.298-3.299 5.963 24.739 117.224-3.679 2.791 3.679 34.634-2.284 6.09 4.187 18.269 10.403 5.709-7.231 21.948-10.403 19.284v16.112L17 352.306l-3.679 15.985L5.202 391l3.932 28.164 13.828 18.522h18.269l17.381-3.299c4.144-5.075 12.433-15.554 12.433-16.873v26.895l-3.679-1.903-8.754 3.425-9.007 7.485-5.836 14.716-4.821 15.097 2.284 21.948 5.075 14.59 3.299 9.388h4.185l4.821 6.47h8.754l3.679 19.284v37.679l-1.396 41.104 11.164 57.343-4.44 9.263 6.978 10.657-6.978 11.545-1.776 10.784-3.552 14.336-11.798 30.321 4.187 23.09-4.187 57.597-10.403 6.978v27.274h10.403c1.48 7.061 4.39 21.618 4.187 23.343-.203 1.725 1.015 10.7 1.649 14.97.677 2.875 2.081 8.931 2.284 10.149.254 1.522 9.769 11.164 11.798 13.701 1.624 2.03 9.896 5.158 13.828 6.47 2.241.931 7.003 2.563 8.119 1.649 1.396-1.142 12.687-5.328 14.082-6.47s13.701-17.888 13.955-19.664 8.5-10.657 8.754-13.701c.203-2.436 3.129-3.89 4.567-4.313l12.306-4.694c2.707-.931 8.982-3.299 12.433-5.328 4.313-2.537 6.09 0 9.007 0h14.59v-4.567c-.846-3.382-2.537-10.428-2.537-11.545 0-1.116-2.284-6.046-3.425-8.373v-7.612l5.963-7.866c2.41-6.173 7.536-18.878 8.754-20.298 1.218-1.421-.507-8.036-1.522-11.164l6.851-20.298-2.918-11.545c3.975-6.934 12.078-21.136 12.687-22.455.761-1.649 12.94-27.276 15.224-28.925s.254-23.597 0-27.022c-.203-2.74-4.821-35.058-7.104-50.873 1.226-2.24 3.907-7.003 4.821-8.119 1.142-1.396 4.187-20.806 4.187-23.724v-19.284c5.371-.761 16.67-2.512 18.903-3.425 2.791-1.142 0-3.045 0-5.075 0-1.624 4.651-6.09 6.978-8.119l1.776-7.104 6.47 3.425 4.44-6.724-2.03-23.978c.127-1.692.304-5.455 0-6.978s-3.255-5.285-4.694-6.978l2.284-8.754-4.821-2.284c.845-3.172 2.537-9.794 2.537-10.91v-18.649c0-2.537-4.187-.761-7.358-1.649-2.537-.71-1.058-3.255 0-4.44.464-.591 1.751-1.979 3.172-2.791 1.776-1.015 6.47-7.612 6.47-9.642s-2.284-13.448-2.284-15.985 2.284-13.575 0-17.127-2.537-10.403-4.187-12.433.507-12.687 0-15.478-1.522-10.403-3.172-12.56c-1.319-1.725-2.073-6.386-2.284-8.5v-66.858h-3.933l-14.845-47.575h-4.44c-3.764-15.858-11.342-47.904-11.545-49.224-.254-1.649-5.709-5.836-9.261-8.754s-5.709-3.932-6.471-5.582c-.609-1.319-8.881-2.749-12.94-3.299-.846-2.157-2.613-6.876-2.918-8.5-.304-1.624-4.187-4.821-6.09-6.216-.592-1.565-1.776-5.049-1.776-6.47 0-1.776 1.776-8.119 1.776-9.769 0-1.319-3.045-6.216-4.567-8.5l-10.657-8.373v-3.425l5.075-9.515c.465-1.692 1.116-5.481 0-7.104-1.116-1.624 2.326-6.597 4.187-8.881l4.187-5.455 5.075-9.515-3.299-10.657-5.963-8.119v-7.358h5.963l3.299-5.963-3.299-7.485c-2.622-5.455-8.043-17.051-8.754-19.791-.888-3.425-9.261-7.866-12.433-9.261s-11.164-4.44-14.589-4.44h-17.381c-3.045 0-14.336 3.933-16.366 4.44-1.624.406-9.642 3.214-13.448 4.567l-7.612 8.119L85 96.925c-.93 2.537-3.222 8.018-4.948 9.642-1.725 1.624-.719 12.433 0 17.634Zm132.575 814.097 2.918 6.724 3.172 2.537c.761 1.649 2.487 5.075 3.299 5.582.812.507.846 4.778.761 6.851l1.269 6.216 4.821 2.537 8.5-2.537c4.313-.297 13.219-.913 14.336-1.015 1.396-.127 12.56-3.679 13.321-3.806.609-.101 3.976-4.017 5.582-5.963.337-2.327 1.015-7.155 1.015-7.866 0-.888-3.045-4.821-4.187-5.963s-6.978-2.157-8.881-3.299-8.881 0-10.022 0-4.821-1.015-6.216-1.903c-1.116-.71-7.316-.297-10.276 0h-5.582l-5.455-2.791h-8.373v4.694Z";
```

[Image: Normal page view with p1 selected (thus glowing)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAl3t.jpg)

[Image: SVG Paths - in black p2, in red p1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ap8T.jpg)

[Image: Example of SVG Paths position and dimension of screen size variation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjhiF.png)

Comment: I think what I want to achieve can be summed up as: a way to recognize when the user clicks on one of the people in the photo and also know which one; however, this method must continue to work with any browser window size.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO

It will be super hard to place an outline exactly ah the same place. But there are a few options you could consider

1. Create a sized box of specific width and height so the position of the outline doesn't charge on screen size change
2. You can give a multiplier value to the position to always set the outline at one specific place

```dart
Stack(
 child : Positioned(
   right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1,
  child: Image.asset("outline.png")
  )
)
```

3. You can create the outline file's dimension same as the main image this way you can stack it and it won't change position at all

Comment: The size of the image containing the glowing border is already equivalent to that of the original image, in fact the problem does not lie in the position of the border. I'm afraid I explained myself badly and for this I apologize as I am not a native English speaker, my problem lies in the size and position of the SVG Path that I use to understand if the user clicks on a person and to understand which one. Since this is not a normal asset, unfortunately it is not easy to resize and reposition it dynamically (the last two photos are examples for this).

Comment: I am afraid that the solutions you proposed are unfortunately not applicable in this case because the third does not apply to the problem, the second does not take into account the scale and the first, as I had tried to use it, did not solve the problem. Thanks anyway, however if you have other ideas I couldn't be happier to read them.